# Pine script william rsi strategy not working

Tags: pine-script

i want to get long and short when percentR cross over -20 and crossover -80 but my 'when' condition is not working

```
strategy("Williams %R", shorttitle="%R", format=format.price, precision=2)
length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)
_pr(length) =>
    max = highest(length)
    min = lowest(length)
    100 * (close - max) / (max - min)
percentR = _pr(length)
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, comment="buy", when=crossover(percentR, -20))
strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, comment="sell", when=crossunder(percentR, -80))
```

Comment: In ver 4 you can just use wpr(14) , you don't have to calculate %R yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to works fine. I've changed your position sizing to use 2% of equity. On some markets with big contract values you may need to increase the starting capital to be able to enter positions.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Williams %R", shorttitle="%R", format=format.price, precision=2, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 2)
length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)
_pr(length) =>
    max = highest(length)
    min = lowest(length)
    100 * (close - max) / (max - min)
percentR = _pr(length)
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, comment="buy", when=crossover(percentR, -20))
strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, comment="sell", when=crossunder(percentR, -80))
plot(percentR)
hline(-20)
hline(-80)
plotchar(crossover(percentR, -20), "crossover(percentR, -20)", "▲", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(crossunder(percentR, -80), "crossunder(percentR, -80)", "▼", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]